# How do we ensure that the datatable will automatically update itself after we execute an update query after clicking a button

Tags: r, database, postgresql, shiny, shinydashboard

Good day all,

I am planning to make my datatable automatically update itself after an update query is executed (by pressing the respective button). So what happen now is the following:

1. The user will click on the import database button to directly import the data into the database.
2. The user will then click on the respective button as shown below (completed, in progress and Done). Clicking on any of these button will result in an update query to update the SQL database.
   [image]

3.The user will then have to click on "Import data" to refresh the datatable.

#### What do I need?

I am planning to omit the need for the user to click on the import data again to refresh the datatable. Instead, the datatable will automatically refresh itself whenever a button is clicked.

The UI section for this tab:

```
            # Extract data from server, edit and reupload 
            tabItem(
                
                tabName="data_edit",
                
                fluidRow(
                    
                    box(width=2,
                        
                        background = "blue",
                        
                        h4("Step 1: Import SQL data"), # Step 1: Import SQL data
                        
                        actionBttn(inputId = "import_button", 
                                   label = "Import data",
                                   color = "primary",
                                   style = "material-flat"),
                        
                        br(),
                        br(),
                        
                        h4("Step 2: Make adjustment on main panel and choose status:"),
                        
                        
                        actionBttn(inputId = "completed_button", 
                                   label = "Completed",
                                   color = "success",
                                   style = "material-flat"),
                        br(),
                        br(),
                        actionBttn(inputId = "in_progress_button", 
                                   label = "In Progress",
                                   color = "warning",
                                   style = "material-flat"),
                        br(),
                        br(),
                        actionBttn(inputId = "not_done_button", 
                                   label = "Not Done",
                                   color = "danger",
                                   style = "material-flat"),
                        br(),
                        br(),
                        h4("Step 3: Click on 'IMPORT DATA' again to refresh!")
                    
                        ), 
                    
                    DT::dataTableOutput({
                        "sql_file"
                    }),
```

The Server.R file for this section:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$import_button, {
    pw <- {
      "pw"
    }
    
    # loads the PostgreSQL driver
    drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
    
    # creates a connection to the postgres database
    # note that "con" will be used later in each connection to the database
    con <- dbConnect(drv, 
                      dbname = "test_db",
                      host = "10.22.71.121", port = 5432,
                      user = "user", password = pw)
    
    #query the database and store the data in datafame
    getQuery <- reactive({
    
    sql_df <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from apple ;")
    return(sql_df)
    })

    # Convert sql data to datatable
    output$sql_file <- DT::renderDataTable({

      DT::datatable(getQuery(),
                    style = "default",
                    filter = 'top',
                    options = list(pageLength = 16,
                                   autoWidth = FALSE,
                                   scrollY = 650,
                                   scrollX = 500))

    })
  
    
    # Exporting changes to SQL database
    
    # Completed button
    observeEvent(input$completed_button, {
      s = getQuery()$row[input$sql_file_rows_selected]
      
      # Change the "status" column in the dataframe as "Done"
      for (i in s){
        query <- sprintf("UPDATE public.apple SET status='completed' WHERE row = %s", i)
        dbSendQuery(con, query)
        cat("\nUpdated as completed for: ", i)
        session$reload()
      }

    })
    
    # In Progress button
    observeEvent(input$in_progress_button, {
      s = getQuery()$row[input$sql_file_rows_selected]
      
      # Change the "Status" column in the dataframe as "Done"
      for (i in s){
        query <- sprintf("UPDATE public.apple SET status='in_progress' WHERE row = %s", i)
        dbSendQuery(con, query)
        cat("\nUpdated as in progress for: ", i)
        session$reload()
      }
      
    })
    
    # Not done button
    observeEvent(input$not_done_button, {
      s = getQuery()$row[input$sql_file_rows_selected]
      
      # Change the "Status" column in the dataframe as "Done"
      for (i in s){
        query <- sprintf("UPDATE public.apple SET status='not_done' WHERE row = %s", i)
        dbSendQuery(con, query)
        cat("\nUpdated as not done for: ", i)
        session$reload()
      }
      
    })
    
    
    # Disconnect the database after user exit the application. Best solution to resolve connection expire issue.
    session$onSessionEnded(function(){
      dbDisconnect(con)
    }) 
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `eventReactive` should address your need.  Try this

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$import_button, {
    pw <- {
      "pw"
    }
    
    # loads the PostgreSQL driver
    drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
    
    # creates a connection to the postgres database
    # note that "con" will be used later in each connection to the database
    con <- dbConnect(drv, 
                     dbname = "test_db",
                     host = "10.22.71.121", port = 5432,
                     user = "user", password = pw)
    
    #query the database and store the data in datafame
    getQuery <- reactive({
      sql_df <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from apple ;")
      return(sql_df)
    })
    DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=getQuery())
    
    # Convert sql data to datatable
    output$sql_file <- DT::renderDataTable({
      
      DT::datatable(DF1$data,
                    style = "default",
                    filter = 'top',
                    options = list(pageLength = 16,
                                   autoWidth = FALSE,
                                   scrollY = 650,
                                   scrollX = 500))
      
    })
    
    # Exporting changes to SQL database
    
    # Completed button
    observeEvent(input$completed_button, {
      s = getQuery()$row[input$sql_file_rows_selected]
      
      # Change the "status" column in the dataframe as "Done"
      for (i in s){
        query <- sprintf("UPDATE public.apple SET status='completed' WHERE row = %s", i)
        dbSendQuery(con, query)
        cat("\nUpdated as completed for: ", i)
        session$reload()
      }
      
    })
    DF1C <- eventReactive(input$completed_button, {
      sql_dfc <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from apple ;")
      return(sql_dfc)
    })
    DF1$data <- DF1C
    
    # In Progress button
    observeEvent(input$in_progress_button, {
      s = getQuery()$row[input$sql_file_rows_selected]
      
      # Change the "Status" column in the dataframe as "Done"
      for (i in s){
        query <- sprintf("UPDATE public.apple SET status='in_progress' WHERE row = %s", i)
        dbSendQuery(con, query)
        cat("\nUpdated as in progress for: ", i)
        session$reload()
      }
      
    })
    DF1P <- eventReactive(input$in_progress_button, {
      sql_dfp <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from apple ;")
      return(sql_dfp)
    })
    DF1$data <- DF1P
    
    # Not done button
    observeEvent(input$not_done_button, {
      s = getQuery()$row[input$sql_file_rows_selected]
      
      # Change the "Status" column in the dataframe as "Done"
      for (i in s){
        query <- sprintf("UPDATE public.apple SET status='not_done' WHERE row = %s", i)
        dbSendQuery(con, query)
        cat("\nUpdated as not done for: ", i)
        session$reload()
      }
      
    })
    DF1ND <- eventReactive(input$not_done_button, {
      sql_dfnd <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from apple ;")
      return(sql_dfnd)
    })
    DF1$data <- DF1ND
    
    # Disconnect the database after user exit the application. Best solution to resolve connection expire issue.
    session$onSessionEnded(function(){
      dbDisconnect(con)
    }) 
  })
}
```